# How to correctly return std::type_info from class method in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class template which should be able to return its template type via `std::type_info`:

```
template <class factType>
class Belief : public BeliefRoot
{
    /* ... */

    factType m_Fact;

    std::type_info GetBeliefType() const override
    {
        return typeid(m_Fact);
    }
};
```

But compiling that class gives me the following error:

*error C2280: 'type_info::type_info(const type_info &)': attempting to reference a deleted function*

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is unrelated to templates, it's caused because `type_info` is non-copyable. Every `type_info` object you need is already compiled into your program, and `typeid()` doesn't make a new one, it returns a const reference to the existing one.

You should make your `GetBeliefType` function return by `const` reference:

```
const std::type_info& GetBeliefType() const override
```

Comment: That statement is false. It would be true if `typeid()` constructed a new object, but it doesn't. The object it returns a reference to persists for the lifetime of the program.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for me. For the records: I needed to return a `const` reference, like so: `const std::type_info& GetBeliefType() const override`.

Comment: No problem. I've edited my answer to add the `const` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [this document](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info), you'll find that

> The `type_info` class is neither CopyConstructible nor ...

Therefore you cannot return a copy of it. The error message tells you the same thing, as `type_info::type_info(const type_info &)` is indeed the non-existing copy constructor that you attempt to use.

Solution: You can return a reference instead. This is because

> The [typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) expression is lvalue expression which refers to an object with static storage duration, of the polymorphic type const std::type_info or of some type derived from it.